# Clear one text box or a div after writing something in another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two `text boxes` or two `divs` with same class ,and I want to clear first `textbox` after writing something in the second. How can I do this??

```
<html>
  <body>

    <div class="school">
     First <input class="abc" type="text" name="first">
    <br><br>
     Second <input class="abc" type="text" name="second">

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question does't tell about checkboxes

Comment: @melvin sorry these are textboxes not checkboxes .

Comment: I can see only one div

Comment: @AliAthar See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code using **input** event.
https://api.jquery.com/on/

> If the second input has an input event, the first input will be
>   empty.

```
$('input[name="second"]').on('input', function(){
  $('input[name="first"]').val('')
})
```

```js
$('input[name="second"]').on('input', function(){
  $('input[name="first"]').val('')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="school">
     First <input class="abc" type="text" name="first">
    <br><br>
     Second <input class="abc" type="text" name="second">

    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.change()` jQuery function to check if second textfield has changed or not. On change you can write code to clear first textbox

Html Code

```
<input type="text" name="text1" id="text1">
<input type="text" name="text2" id="text2">
```

JQuery Code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#text2').change(function(){
        $('#text1').val('');
      });
    });
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8a5v9L3d/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByName("first")[0].addEventListener("blur", function (){
     document.getElementsByName("second")[0].value = "";
})
document.getElementsByName("second")[0].addEventListener("blur", function (){
     document.getElementsByName("first")[0].value = "";
})
```

Note : if you want to to clear other input when you click on an input field then use focus event and if you want to clear other input when user changes input value then use change event or keypress event as per your requirement